# Safe use of POST vars into database

Tags: php, mysql

Dear community it has been a while since i wrote database applications, just to be sure I have a simple question:

Is the PHP code down here safe to use? I have a basic DA installation with php 5.3.8 so magic quotes should be disabled.

Greetings,

```
 <?php
    $id =  ( mysql_real_escape_string( stripslashes ($_POST['id'])));
    $naam = ( mysql_real_escape_string( stripslashes  ($_POST['naam'])));
    $bericht =  ( mysql_real_escape_string ( stripslashes ($_POST['bericht'])));

    if ($id and $naam and $bericht) {

    $databsestring = "<div class=\"reactie\"><h3>".$naam." op ".date ("F j, Y").":</h3>" . $bericht . "</div>";

    if ($db_found) {

    $SQL = "UPDATE xxxxx_comments SET comments = CONCAT (comments,'".$databsestring."') WHERE id='".$id."'";
    $result = mysql_query($SQL);


    mysql_close($db_handle);

    }
    ?>
```

Comment: just my opinion but I would recommend a php framework like http://cakephp.org so you never have to worry about this type of question =)

Comment: use of `mysql_query` is "discouraged". You should begin to use other PHP extensions, like PDO or MySQLi. They allow you to `prepare` your queries, making sql injection factually impossible. Other than that, you seem to have a rather strange understanding of the "relational" part of RDBs, adding "comments" by concatenating them into a single field is rather strange... What would you do to delete a single one of them?

Comment: you're escaping, so it should may be ok. but stripslashes will mangle your strings if magic_quotes isn't enabled to begin with. any legitimate backslashes will be removed.

Comment: Well I explainded that to the customer but its what they want....  stripslashes is'nt needed ? thx for all your anwsers!

Comment: mysql_real_escape_string is enough

Comment: Ok i removed stripslashes now if i use 'test' it wil return /'test/' might magic qoutes be enabled after all?

Answer (score 2):

mysql_* is deprecated, use mysqli or PDO to safely store data.

For example:

```
    $add_user = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO `users` SET  `name`=?, `email`=?, `encrypted_password`=?");
    $add_user->bind_param("sss",$name,$email,$hash["encrypted"]);
    $add_user->execute()
```

Using prepared statements is a safe way to avoin sql injections

Comment: Definitely PDO. You can avoid the ugly question marks in the prepared statement.

Comment: Beauty is in the eye of the beholder :)

Comment: Mysql_ isn't deprecated and it will take long before they will make it deprecated.

Comment: Wow, no need to downvote him. mysql_ is discouraged and WILL be removed in future versions. Why write code that WILL break, or worse, get your database hacked? Upvoting to compensate for the a$$hat.

Comment: +1 
http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php recommends to use mysqli or pdo.

Comment: Could I just change all mysql to mysqli ? What is the difference in safety between the two?

Comment: Sure you can change all your code from mysql to mysqli. But you have to do this manually. mysqli is an improved extension of mysql. It is therefore for your own best to use mysqli. It has more features as well as better performance. More Info is [here](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.overview.php). Why prepared statements are injection safe is explained [here](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php)